# Compare string values from a column value based on multiple ffields in R

Tags: r

I am trying to compare the text in a column based on other column values using levenshteinSim.

I have sample data as:

```
d1  d2  d3  
A   100 This is not a test for the project  
A   100 This is not a test for the project  
A   100 This is not a test for the project  
A   300 This is test for the project  
A   300 This is test for the project  
A   300 This is test for the project  
A   400 This is test for the project XYX  
A   500 This is not a test for the project  
B   10  This is  a new project  
B   20  This is about vegetables  
B   30  This is about animals  
B   10  This is  a new project  
B   20  This is about vegetables  
B   30  This is about animals  
B   10  This is  a new project  
B   20  This is about vegetables  
B   30  This is about animals
```

I want to compare text in D3 and get the percentage match based on d1 and d2.

After that I am not able to apply levenshteinSim to get the % match of text in d3 based on d1 and d2.

The sample output will be like:

```
d1 d2 d3 match_percentage
A 100 This is not a test for the project  100%    
A 300 This is test for the project         56%
```

etc etc
d3 values to be compared to all other for same d1.

Sample code:

First I found out the unique records from the df:

```
abc <- read.csv("Duplicate_test.csv",header = TRUE)

def<-abc  %>%
group_by(d1,d2) %>%
mutate(num_dups = n(),
     dup_id = row_number()) %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(is_duplicated = dup_id > 1)

unique_records <- filter(def,is_duplicated == FALSE)
```

Comment: How do you calculate `match_percentage` for each unique value of `d1` and `d2`?

Comment: I want to compare each value against other value based on D1 and the function returns the percentage match. The max match percentage can be final value

Comment: If there is only One record for d1 then match percentage will be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `distinct` to get unique rows and for each `d1` calculate the `max` match percentage between `d3` values.

```
library(dplyr)

abc %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(d1) %>%
  mutate(match_percentage = map_dbl(row_number(), 
                    ~max(RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim(d3[.x], d3[-.x]))) * 100)

#   d1       d2 d3                                 match_percentage
#  <chr> <int> <chr>                                         <dbl>
#1 A       100 This is not a test for the project            100  
#2 A       300 This is test for the project                   87.5
#3 A       400 This is test for the project XYX               87.5
#4 A       500 This is not a test for the project            100  
#5 B        10 This is  a new project                         45.5
#6 B        20 This is about vegetables                       70.8
#7 B        30 This is about animals                          70.8
```

**data**

```
abc <- structure(list(d1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), d2 = c(100L, 100L, 
100L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 
30L, 10L, 20L, 30L), d3 = c("This is not a test for the project", 
"This is not a test for the project", "This is not a test for the project", 
"This is test for the project", "This is test for the project", 
"This is test for the project", "This is test for the project XYX", 
"This is not a test for the project", "This is  a new project", 
"This is about vegetables", "This is about animals", "This is  a new project", 
"This is about vegetables", "This is about animals", "This is  a new project", 
"This is about vegetables", "This is about animals")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, in this we got just two records, for D1=A there are four unique records and expected output is 4 records and %age match of each D3 value against each other . Each text string to be compared with rest of other three and get the max percentage match. Same for record 2 and so on.

Comment: I see. Can you check if the updated answer is what you are looking for? @user13472171